# Convert Rdd[Vector] to Rdd[Double]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

How do I convert csv to Rdd[Double]? I have the error: cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Unit]) at this line:

```
val kd = new KernelDensity().setSample(rows)
```

My full code is here:

```
   import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix
    import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.KernelDensity
    import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
    import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

class KdeAnalysis {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("sample").setMaster("local")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val DATAFILE: String = "C:\\Users\\ajohn\\Desktop\\spark_R\\data\\mass_cytometry\\mass.csv"
  val rows = sc.textFile(DATAFILE).map {
    line => val values = line.split(',').map(_.toDouble)
      Vectors.dense(values)
  }.cache()



  // Construct the density estimator with the sample data and a standard deviation for the Gaussian
  // kernels
  val rdd : RDD[Double] = sc.parallelize(rows)
  val kd = new KernelDensity().setSample(rdd)
    .setBandwidth(3.0)

  // Find density estimates for the given values
  val densities = kd.estimate(Array(-1.0, 2.0, 5.0))
}
```

Comment: I don't see any place in your where you can get `RDD[Unit]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `rows` is a `RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]` following line cannot work:

```
val rdd : RDD[Double] = sc.parallelize(rows)
```

`parallelize` expects `Seq[T]` and `RDD` is not a `Seq`.

Even if this part worked as you expect your input is simply wrong. A correct argument for `KernelDensity.setSample` is either `RDD[Double]` or `JavaRDD[java.lang.Double]`. It looks like it doesn't support a multivariate data at this moment.

Regarding a question from the tile you can `flatMap`

```
rows.flatMap(_.toArray)
```

or even better when you create `rows`

```
val rows = sc.textFile(DATAFILE).flatMap(_.split(',').map(_.toDouble)).cache()
```

but I doubt it is really what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have prepared this code, please evaluate if it can help you out ->

```
val doubleRDD = rows.map(_.toArray).flatMap(x => x)
```